# Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath in solr

Tags: java, xml, apache, solr

problem

- i cannot access solr admin page.
- when i run url on localsystem: 
  http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=new_core&configSet=basic_configs

response

```
    <response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">400</int>
    <int name="QTime">17</int>
    </lst>
    <lst name="error">
    <str name="msg">
    Error CREATEing SolrCore 'new_core': Unable to create core: new_core Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/var/lib/tomcat7/solr/new_core/conf'
    </str>
    <int name="code">400</int>
    </lst>
    </response>
```

- i have reffered link : https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin
- solr.xml  code

  ```
  <solr persistent="false">
      <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
          <core name="afeef" instanceDir="afeef" />
      </cores>
  </solr>
  ```

error:

```
  SolrCore Initialization Failures
    afeef: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/afeef/solrconfig.xml
    coreX: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/path_to_instance_directory/config_file_name.xml
    new_core: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /var/lib/tomcat7/solr/new_core/solrconfig.xml
```

- when i run this cmd

  ps aux|grep java

  tomcat7  23192  0.7  2.0 2579744 161852 ?      Sl   16:22   0:11 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat7/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
  mohd     24047  0.0  0.0  15948  2276 pts/14   S+   16:45   0:00 grep --color=auto java
- it was working properly suddenly it throws error .

Answer (score 7):

Go to solr core admin folder. 
In mac if you installed it from homebrew, it is `/opt/homebrew/var/lib/solr`

Now delete the core, that you tried to create and recreate from terminal

```
solr delete -c my_solr

solr create_core -c y_solr
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentionned in the wiki that you referenced in the link , instanceDir parameter in the http request is a required parameter. config, schema & dataDir parameters are optional. (Default is to look for solrconfig.xml/schema.xml inside instanceDir. Default place to look for dataDir depends on solrconfig.xml.)
Example of 
**Create Request**

```
    http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=path_to_instance_directory&
config=config_file_name.xml&schema=schema_file_name.xml&dataDir=data
```

Comment: hey frnd error:
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'coreX': Unable to create core: coreX Caused by: Premature end of file.

Comment: i tried http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=afeef&config=solrconfig.xml&schema=schema.xml&dataDir=afeef

Comment: check if folder named'path_to_instance_directory exists' and does it contain config.xml and schema.xml if it is it might be privilege problem and the application needs more privilege to access that folder, try to put your configuration folder in a folder wich is not resticted

Answer (score 0):

4 Years on but this was never answered.

The example from the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/coreadmin-api.html#coreadmin-create) worked for me with version 8.6:

http://:localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=core-name&instanceDir=path/to/dir&config=solrconfig.xml&dataDir=data