# Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath in solr while creating solr core through API

Tags: solr, solrj

Found this post with similar problem . Posting as New one as its very old thread.
[Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407796/cant-find-resource-solrconfig-xml-in-classpath-in-solr#comment58519446_35408943)

Getting below error while trying to create Solr CORE from API.

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 400,
        "QTime": 4
    },
    "error": {
        "metadata": [
            "error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
            "root-error-class",
            "org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceNotFoundException"
        ],
        "msg": "Error CREATEing SolrCore 'coreX': Unable to create core [coreX] Caused by: Can't find resource 'config_file_name.xml' in classpath or '/home/batchhub/solr-7.4.0/server/solr/path_to_instance_directory'",
        "code": 400
    }
}
```

API

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreX&instanceDir=path_to_instance_directory&
config=config_file_name.xml&schema=schema_file_name.xml&dataDir=data
```

How to Solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceDir` parameter in the collections API `CREATE` should referer to a real path, not `path_to_instance_directory`. Same for `config` parameter.